# Habilitar botones con jQuery

Tags: jquery

Estoy realizando una página web que realiza una encuesta por pasos. Para eso, divido cada sección de preguntas con unos `<fieldset></fieldset>`. Hay campos que son obligatorios, y para eso, inhabilito todos los botones con jQuery.

Al llenar los campos obligatorios, el botón se habilita para seguir al siguiente `<fieldset>` y proseguir con las demás preguntas (son 9 fieldset).

Al iniciar el documento, inhabilito los botones con esta línea:

```
$("fieldset").find('button[class="btn btn-next"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Al momento de llenar los campos obligatorios, se habilitan los botones con este código:

```
$(document).on("click", ".obligatorios", function() {
    var fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
    var valid = true;
    fieldset.find(".obligatorios").each(function() {
         if($(this). prop("checked") == false) {
              valid = false;
         }
    });
    if(valid) {
         $(fieldset).find('button[class="btn btn-next"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
         $(fieldset).find('button[class="btn btn-next"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Intento que al iniciar el documento, se me habiliten lo botones a los cuales ya se llenaron los campos. Es decir, si empiezan en el **fieldest número 4, los botones de los fieldset 1, 2 y 3 se habiliten**. He intentado con este código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fieldset = $(document).parents('fieldset');
    var valid = true;
    fieldset.find(".obligatorios").each(function() {
         if($(this). prop("checked") == false) {
              valid = false;
         }
    });
    if(valid) {
         $(fieldset).find('button[class="btn btn-next"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
         $(fieldset).find('button[class="btn btn-next"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Es casi el mismo de arriba, pero no me habilita los botones. Quisiera saber cómo podría resolver ese problema, por favor.

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es seleccionar todos los `fieldset`, recorrerlos y en cada iteración debes preguntar si los campos obligatorios de cada `fieldset` están `check` o no para poder habilitar el botón perteneciente al `fieldset`.

Te recomiendo activar o desactivar la propiedad `disabled` usando el método [.prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) el cual recupera explícitamente los valores de la propiedad.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fieldset = $('fieldset');

    fieldset.each(function(){
      var valid = true;

      $(this).find(".obligatorios").each(function() {
         if($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
              valid = false;
         }
      });

      if(valid) {
         $(this).find('button[class="btn btn-next"]').prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
         $(this).find('button[class="btn btn-next"]').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: No me lo habilita. Sinceramente, no sé porqué.

Comment: @SantiagoCorreaAguirreSanmar te sale algún error de consola o algo? esto debería funcionar

Comment: En realidad parece que no me sale algún error.  El problema es que aún no me toma los input checkeados.